# How to influence the name scope of collated variables / slots?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

**Description**

I wrap TensorFlow model with a loss function in a `model_fn()` for a `tf.estimator.Estimator` instantiation.
Various optimizers (e.g. `tf.train.MomentumOptimizer`, or `tf.train.AdagradOptimizer`) create `Read(_x)` operations for all trainable variables in the model (gamma, beta of batch normalization, kernels of convolutions, ...) when `optimizer.apply_gradients()` is called.
Specifically, they are named as `Read_<num>/ReadVariableOp`, and are of type `tf.Operation`.
The problem is that these variables are created outside of any `tf.variable_scope` or `tf.name_scope` at the root of the `tf.Graph`.
This totally messes up readability in TensorBoard:
[image: Imgur]
The red frame is the actual model. The blue frame encapsulates a tiny fraction of all 300+ read functions.

**Question**

Is there a way how I could wrap all `Read_<num>` Operations in something like a `tf.name_scope()`? Or is there another way to programmatically (i.e. not by clicking with the mouse) remove them from TensorBoard?

**What have I tried**

1. Wrap the call to `apply_gradients()` like this:

   ```
   with tf.name_scope('apply_gradients_to_ns'):
       with tf.variable_scope('apply_gradients_to_vs'):
           minimize_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(
               grads_and_vars=grads_and_vars,
               global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step(),
               name='apply_gradients_to_name'
           )
   ```

   with no effect. Still, the scope of all `Read_<num>` operations is not influenced.
2. Trace the creation of these operations:

   In `tensorflow.python.training.slot_creator.py`, line 179, in `create_zeros_slot(..., colocate_with_primary=True)` triggers a call to `tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope.py`, line 1298, `get_variable(..., use_resource=None)` with `use_resource=True`.
   However, I don't want to mess around in the source code of TensorFlow.
   Also, I conclude that this behavior is intended and I just use it wrong.
   How *should* it be used?
3. Try different distribution strategies: `OneDeviceStrategy`, `MirroredStrategy`.
   Both produce a similar effect.
   The only difference is that the `MirroredStrategy` creates `group_deps_<num>` variables.

**Code to reproduce this effect**, a more detailed description, and two more screenshots can be found in this repository: https://github.com/patzm/tf-estimator-distribute-so

Comment: Would you mind giving a reproducible example? I cannot locate these `Read_x` operations on my TensorBoard and your screenshot is too small to read.

Comment: @Richard_wth sorry for the late reply and thanks for you to prompt that a working example would be good :-) I wrote one and added the link above.